# Aggregate, DomainEvent with Prooph

Tags: php, events, aggregate, domain-events, prooph

I'm developing an application which scrapes HTML feeds after it authenticates.  These websites only support email/password authentication, but some integrations may require additional information.  So my question is now specific should I get when creating domain events and aggregates?  I've worked with Prooph and have created simple aggregates and domain events which only deal with a single entity type.  But now I'm wondering if aggregates and domain events should be specific towards these third-party website scrapers.  Should there be an event per feed scraper, or is creating a generic event and aggregate better?  The properties of each aggregate could differ.

```
class WebsiteA extends AggregateRoot
{
    private $id;

    private $email;

    private $password;

    public static function initiate($id, $email, $password)
    {...}
}

class WebsiteB extends AggregateRoot
{
    private $id;

    private $email;

    private $password;

    private $accountIds = [];

    private $userSalt;

    public static function initiate($id, $email, $password, $accountIds, $userSalt)
    {...}
}
```

Then something similar for the domain events

```
class WebsiteAWasInitiated extends AggregateChanged
{
    public static function withUser($id, $email, $password){}
}

class WebsiteBWasInitiated extends AggregateChanged
{
    public static function withUser($id, $email, $password, $accountIds, $userSalt){}
}
```

Or would it be better to create a single aggregate and domain event? Which both websites use.  Keep in mind, the list of supported websites will grow.

```
class WebsiteScraper extends AggregateRoot
{
    private $id;

    private $credentials;

    public static function initiate($id, $credentials)
    {...}
}

class WebsiteScraperWasInitiated extends AggregateChanged
{
    public static function withUser($id, $credentials){}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is more a DDD related question and the answer is "it depends". Will your amount of scrapers grow so much, that you cannot add code for every single one of them? Then try to use a generic scraper aggregate. If your amount of scrapers is limited, you can use custom ones for every one of them.